# How to move a table row in Apple iWork Pages?

Tags: iwork-pages

Is it possible to drag a table row to a new position in order to reorder them?

Things we've tried

- Drag the row: either swaps or overwrites (perhaps depending on Pages version?)
- Drag the row with `alt`: overwrites the target and leaves the original row.
- `Cut` leaves a blank row, and `paste` overwrites, which requires manual addition of blank row.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new row below the row you want to insert below.

Example:

```
Rows
1
2
3
4
```

You want to move 4 between 1 and 2.  Insert a blank row below 1, and then drop 4 on the blank row.

```
1
(new blank)
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not much better than the cut-paste solution.